# Dylib version error when running Delphi 10 Seattle applications on OS X

Tags: macos, delphi, delphi-10-seattle

RAD Studio 10 Seattle, Delphi personality. Created new app from scratch and put on it one button and added ShowMessage("Hello') in its OnClick event.

Installed PAServer17.pkg on Mac (10.10 Yosemite, XCode 7). Started.

RAD Studio automatically installed SDK (10.11, that seems to be the only SDK available) from the Mac. Then the program deploys. But when the PAServer tries to start it, I get the following error:

```
================================================ 
Process Control Server Started pid 2422 exe  
built Aug  7 2015 sentinelFunc 2424 dyld:
Library not loaded: /usr/lib/libSystem.dylib   
Referenced from:
/Users/primoz/PAServer/scratch-dir/gabr-Milena/Project1.app/Contents/MacOS/Project1
Reason: Incompatible library version: Project1 requires version
112.0.97 or later, but libSystem.B.dylib provides version 1.0.
================================================
```

Tried cleaning up PAServer scratch area and reinstalling XCode 7. Checked that I only have one libSystem.B.dylib on PC (got it with the 10.11 SDK). There *are* multiple copies of that library on the OS X but I don't dare messing with them.

Any ideas?

Comment: I get exactly the same error targeting iOS (using Delphi 10 Seattle after upgrading to Xcode 7)

Comment: I solved it by upgrading my iPad to iOS 9, but since you are targeting OSX, that is of course not an option for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the problem lies in the 10.11 SDK (or Delphi not knowing how to handle it).

By the advice I got on Google+ from Antonello Carlomagno I did this:

- Downloaded Xcode 6.4 from https://developer.apple.com/xcode/download/ (it's hiding in the Additional Tools link at the bottom).
- Extracted 10.10 SDK from Xcode_6.4.dmg (/Xcode/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs) and copied it to /Applications/Xcode/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs.

I then imported this SDK into the Delphi 10 and OS X compilation is now working.

Comment: but then - how we can compile for iOS9 ?

Comment: I had problems with OS X and that's what this question is about. iOS 9 works for me with XCode 7.